# SQL Server - copy all data from all tables from one server to another server with identical structure

Tags: sql-server

I want to copy all data from all tables from one SQL server database to another existing SQL server database of the same structure. I have a script to initially delete all contents of all tables in my output database before proceeding so that it is 'fresh' for the copy.

I understand that 'select into' statements can get this done but I want to be able to do it in bulk. I want to emulate the behavior that works very well in Management Studio of:

1. Right-click a DB
2. Select 'Tasks'
3. Select 'Export Data...'

In here, I can select an output DB and then select all tables. The transfer goes straight through without issue. I cannot find a command line way to achieve this.

The reason I am after this is that we want a daily copy of the prod database in a testing environment, so need to task schedule this process to run each night.

Due to some contstraints, I can't use a bacpac in this case.

Comment: Backup / restore?

Comment: I agree with @Roger. Based on what you've explained, backup/restore is the best option

Comment: I guess link server won't do the trick: you will still have to build a corresponding query! However, I did something similar using SSIS... I copy tables, views, indexes etc. ... any reason why you need a plain command? Or would SSIS be an option?

Answer (score 0):

Using the import/export task in SSMS, the last step has 2 options. Run immediately or save as SSIS package. So - save it as a SSIS package. You can then run this package whenever you want. And yes - you will need to do this twice. Once for export, once for import. You can also do exactly the same thing using SSIS btw.

So how do you execute a package from the command line? Like you do for any question, you should search first. Some suggestions/examples are [here](https://www.sqlshack.com/ways-use-execute-sql-server-integration-services-packages/).

And if needed, you can schedule this using the agent.